# литература по linux

Tags: linux, книги

Ищу книги по linux, их весьма много и что-то конкретное выбрать не просто. Цель изучить устройство ос(но не лезть в сорцы) и научиться пользоваться осью на хорошем продвинутом уровне. На данный момент использую debian, хочу перейти на arch, но знаний не хватает.

Comment: Например, можно почитать Роберт Лав: [Ядро Linux. Описание процесса разработки](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/17925734/) и [Linux. Системное программирование](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/26420096/) (мне обе понравились)

Comment: если хотите изучать программу linux, то нежелание «лезть» в её исходники выглядит несколько странным. если же хотите изучать операционную систему, то, для начала, стоит определиться, какую именно операционную систему вам интересно изучить. (подсказка: операционная система linux так никогда и не была дописана — торвальдс ограничился лишь написанием ядра операционной системы).

Comment: есть такой linux HOWTO

Answer (score 6):

Субъективно, но всё же. Полезными были (и остаются) [Мэттью, Стоунз "Основы программирования в Linux"](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4307775/), [Троан, Джонсон "Разработка приложений в среде Linux"](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3261770/) - это основы, но новичку дает неплохое представление.

Пробовал читать [Митчелла "Программирование для Linux. Профессиональный подход"](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/986013/). Пошла тяжело - слишком быстро для начинающего адепта) Обзор системных вызовов показался описанным очень вскользь. Поэтому предыдущим двум мое личное предпочтение.

Думаю, для более глубокого понимания подойдет [Kerrisk "The Linux Programming Interface: A Linux and UNIX System Programming Handbook"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593272200)

Для пользователя linux может подойти книжка [Граннемана "Linux. Необходимый код и команды"](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3178480/). Освещены минимальные действия в консоли. Более мощные приемы можно подсмотреть у [Peek, Powers, O'Reilly, Loukides в "Unix Power Tools"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596003302.do)